# PhpStorm not synchronizing new local files

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.1

I have a large project with multiple repositories. Whenever I create a new file in one of my repositories with a build tool like gulp or webpack I don't see any changes show up unless I manually right click my root directory and click `synchronize selected files`.

It does not matter how long I wait it only works if I do this. Is there something I could tweak or change to possible effect this and maybe help me get rid of this problem?

I am syncing with a virtual machine but edits or lightning fast and I have caching turned off.

Comment: PhpStorm does not really change for externally created/modified files at random. By default it happens when you focus IDE window (switching from another program to PhpStorm) and this option can be turned off. In most other cases you will indeed need to use `File | Synchronize` for IDE to re-read project files looking for changes. At the same time IDE has file system watcher/notifier .. but it may not work depending on different moments (where files are located (local/network); what OS; any symbolic links; etc) -- some info can be found in `idea.log` (mostly when it turned off completely)